# Okta OpenID Connect how to Verify ID_TOKEN & extract data?

Tags: node.js, jwt, openid-connect, okta, okta-api

If you visit the link.
https://developer.okta.com/docs/guides/validate-id-tokens/overview/

- At the end you will find Okta **Libraries to Help You Verify ID Tokens**
- I'm currently using `Node.js`, when you click on it it will take you to https://github.com/okta/okta-oidc-js/tree/master/packages/jwt-verifier
- The strange thing is that the Github page shows **This library does not yet verify id tokens**

---

My Questions?

1. How can I verify & extract user specific data from ID Token?
2. In NodeJS how can I then protect specific routes by writing a function which only allows access to routes when user is verified.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Why do you want to verify an ID token? There's not much you can do with an ID token except for look at it. Validation of an access token is much more important since it can be used to access secure data.

Comment: @MattRaible Thanks for replying. Yeah, I agree with you. For me, the most important thing is to extract data from the ID token and use it to protect the routes. Please let me know if you need any further explanation.